# iPhone UIWebView suddently turns to black after a few seconds

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

This is bizarre.  On at least on iPhone, (but not the test iPod or simulator) a UIWebView suddenly turns black. I can some feint outlines of some images and the title bar is just fine, only the WebView.  Furthermore, this is code that has been basically working fine for quite a while now.  Some very minor adjustments and formatting have been perhaps applied but that's it.

I'm at a loss on how to figure this one out.  Any help much appreciated.

Below is the code snippet (proprietary info changed), although I'm doubtful if it will provide any illuminating details.  As I've mentioned, this code has worked before and currently on iPods fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    @try
    {
        NSString* infoUrl = @"www.example.com/index.html";
        NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:infoUrl]];
        if (htmlData != NULL)
        {
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:urlAddress contents:htmlData attributes:nil];
        }

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlUrl];

        [newsWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        NSLog(@"exception: %@: %@",
              [e name], [e reason]);
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code with us, it sure do will help

Comment: Perhaps this is related to low memory conditions? Are you getting memory warnings before this happens?

Comment: @hundreth.  I would doubt it, but I'm going to check into it.  Thanks.

Comment: I might of had a corrupted background image.  In any case, did fresh installs and this went away.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. However I found there is a script error in my javascript code. After fixing the bug, I can't reproduce the sudden black screen issue.